# Laravel 6 Error - Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\GetContentController::$request

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to send form data including files (if any) without `form` tag via Ajax request. However, I am getting the following error message

`Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\GetContentController::$request`

**Here are my codes**

**Controller**

```
public function GetContentController($params){
    


$CandidateFullName = $this->request->CandidateFullName;

$CandidateLocation=$this->request->CandidateLocation;

//inserted into database after validation and a json object is sent back
```

**Web.php**

```
Route::match(['get', 'post'], '{controller}/{action?}/{params1?}/{params2?}', function ($controller, $action = 'index', $params1 = '',$params2 = '') {
    $params = explode('/', $params1);
    $params[1] = $params2;
    $app = app();
    $controller = $app->make("\App\Http\Controllers\\" . ucwords($controller) . 'Controller');
    return $controller->callAction($action, $params);
})->middleware('supadminauth');
```

**Blade**

```
<input type="text" id="CandidateFullName" name="CandidateFullName" class="form-control">

<input type="text" id="CandidateLocation" name="CandidateLocation" class="form-control">
<button id="final_submit">Submit</button>

<script>

$('#final_submit').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();

var  data = {};
     data['CandidateFullName']= $('#CandidateFullName').val();
     data['CandidateLocation']=$('#CandidateLocation').val();
submitSaveAndNext(data)

});

function submitSaveAndNext(data){ 
    //console.log(data);
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{csrf_token()}}'
      }
    }); 


 $.ajax({
            type    : "POST", 
            url : '{{url("GetContent/submitContent")}}', //GetContentController ,but without Controller in the end
            dataType  : "json",
            contentType : "application/json",
            data    : JSON.stringify(data),
            success   : function(response){
               
              //console.log("response ",response);
              if(response.message=="success"){ 
                swal({
                    title:"Success",
                    type: "success",
                });
              }else{
                swal({
                  title:"Sorry! Unable to save data",
                  type:"warning"
                })
              }
            },
            error:function(xhr, status, error){
                
                swal({
                  title:"Sorry! Unable to save data",
                  type:"warning"
                })
            }
          }) //ajax ends
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think controller instance in laravel possess the property having request instance, you'll have to type-hint to obtain the object of the request

```
public function GetContentController($params) {

  // $this->request is the issue
  $CandidateFullName = $this->request-> CandidateFullName;

  $CandidateLocation = $this->request->CandidateLocation;

}
```

So you can try either of the below-given solutions

```
// make sure include the Request class into your controller namespace
public function GetContentController($params, Request $request) {
    
  $CandidateFullName = $request->input('CandidateFullName');
        
  $CandidateLocation = $request->input('CandidateLocation');
        
}
```

Or use the helper function for request

```
public function GetContentController($params) {
      
    $CandidateFullName = request('CandidateFullName');
  
    $CandidateLocation = request('CandidateLocation');
    
 }
```

These links will help you get more details :

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#accessing-the-request
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#method-request

Comment: `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`-> I do have this line included in the controller

Comment: Have you initialized the property $this->request in the constructor of the controller?

Comment: it's not necessary tbh, the above two solutions are preferred ones.

Comment: I am getting this error message `Argument 2 passed to App\Http\Controllers\GetContentController::submitContent() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, string given`

Comment: `submitContent()` is the function in the controller. It is the url to which ajax is sent

Comment: Why would you manually call the controller method from your route file? that too you're exploding the params and then getting the instance from service container? there seems to be something seriously wrong with the implementation. I'll leave it here.

Comment: The design is such that the Controller is created dynamically. So, the URL will include the Controller Name and the COntroller function

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227012/discussion-between-ashu-and-skumar).